# Regulate Water Pumps flow by DC Stepper Motor Driver

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper-motor

I'm an Arduino beginner. I've got 2 x 12V DC water pumps

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/224461221015

plus 12V, 2A AC/DC adapter to feed them.

I would like to regulate the speed (flow) of the pumps programmatically by Arduino. My first idea was to use 2 channel Relay, however, it only supports two states - on/off. Then I discovered this DC Stepper Motor Driver:

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/274521887403

That seems to be a good fit in terms of specifications, but I'm not sure whether it will work with the pumps? It makes me think of whether the DC Stepper Motor Driver may work with only specific motors?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Even though they call that a "stepper motor driver" it's nothing more than a basic H-bridge that can drive *any* brushed DC motors (two per driver).

Comment: I would add that the L298N is a relatively inefficient driver--I might aim for a different driver, like a 6612 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

You can control the speed of the water pumps with a PWM signal by using:

```
analogWrite(PWM_pin, value)
```

Or you can use a cheap transistor like a P2N2222A; here is a [full tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-drive-a-DC-Motor-with-Transistor-Arduino-Tu/).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately after trying it does not work as expected. It has been mentioned that it must be a **BRUSHED** motor and most of these pumps on eBay are **Brushless**.